# Center Vertically drawableLeft of EditText

Tags: android

I'm using the code below :

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/et_add_edittext_button"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/plus"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false" android:clickable="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="32dp" android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

but the drawable stays aligned at the bottom. You can see the result at the image below : 
[image]

Is there a way I can center the `drawableLeft` vertically **wihout** having to use a parent layout and split the editText to `ImageView` and `EditText` ? 
Or should I try and create a custom View so I can achieve the result I want ?

Comment: You create have more control with  a custom view

Comment: @Eenvincible I thought so. I was just wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Let me dig into my code to see how I did it before (center on the left)

Comment: I will be glad if you could provide some code

Comment: Have you considered the latest approach like using TextInputLayout in material design to show hints to users instead of using icons?

Comment: I'm just following the designs they give me. I'm too junior in my team yet to make any recommendations :P